# How to inherite my custom theme?

Tags: android, dialog, styles, themes

I need promote a dialog in service, and I found set the dialog windows type as TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT can work fine :

```
dialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
```

but another issue occurs, I set custom view in my dialog, the component in custom views cannot inherit my theme style, they use the system default theme style.

update: this is my example code:

```
public class AlertDialogService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}   

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_text_entry, null);
    Dialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this, R.style.Theme_My_Dialog_Alert)
        .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_text_entry)
        .setView(textEntryView)
        .create();
    alertDialog.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT);
    alertDialog.show();
}
}
```

Comment: why do you use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT ?

Comment: @pskink if i do not use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT, i show dialog in service will get errors. this is a workaround to fix the error.

Comment: so dont use WindowManager at all, startActivity instead

Comment: @pskink i want to show dialog in service, and the service is run in background, i cannot use the activity's contextWrapper, because the activity maybe destroy at some time

Comment: startActivity from your Service

Comment: @pskink but i want use dialog, not a activity, do you have any idea for use dialog?

Comment: use android:theme ="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"

Comment: did Theme.Dialog work ?

Comment: @pskink I want to use my custom theme style, and the dialog's style has been changed, but the custom view `.setView(textEntryView)`. the textEntryView still use system default style

Comment: did you use. Theme.Dialog or not ?

Comment: @pskink i use activity with Theme.Dialog, it works! but i still want to know why it is cannot work when i use dialog

Comment: probably because of Service' Context

Comment: @pskink actually, i use the AlertDialog.Builder().setMultiChoiceItems() to add some content in the dialog, they will work fine, just i use the custom view and just the custom part view cannot work, i am so confused.

Comment: so check your ctor(Context, AttrSet, int)